# How to lock a DataClass

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using a Linq to Sql connection to collaborate with a database and my windows form application works with multiple threads and this dosen't suite with the DataClass.
I modify the connection to support `MultipleActiveResultSets` and I get this error `"An item with the same key has already been added."` I have searched for this problem and got only 2 answers:

- Use your DataClass only in your main thread;
- Lock the DataClass when you retrieve a table;

I want to `lock` the DataClass and don't know where to lock it, I'm sure that some one used Linq to Sql in multithreading successfully.

Comment: Personally, I would say treat the data-context as a unit-of-work, and don't keep it at all between discreet operations. As a side-effect, since each data-context would be local to some method, threading would cease to be an issue.

Comment: and how do I treat the data-context as a unit-of-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what I was saying in comments, and to answer your question - I would treat all access as a unit-of-work, for example (in some data-access class):

```
public Order GetOrder(int id) {
    // ctx could also be instantiated via an IoC/DI framework, etc
    using(var ctx = CreateDataContext()) {
        return ctx.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
public void AddOrder(Order order) {
    if(order == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("order");
    // ctx could also be instantiated via an IoC/DI framework, etc
    using(var ctx = CreateDataContext()) {
        ctx.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(order);
        ctx.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

etc. Key point: the data-context is not left open indefinitely and re-used by competing threads.